# Colloquial meaning of 'exponential decrease'

Tags: terminology, mathematics

I often have a hard time figuring out exactly what is meant when *exponential/ly* is used outside of mathematics. This is especially true for *exponential decrease*.

Take the sentence:

> The number of fish in the lake has decreased exponentially over the past couple of years

Mathematically this would mean *a while ago the decrease was rapid, but rate of decrease has decreased* (*e<sup>−x</sup>*, left figure), which is a good thing (assuming we want fish in the lake). However I believe that the intent of the sentence is *the number of fish in the lake is decreasing at an increasing rate* (*−e<sup>x</sup>*, right figure).

[image: e^-x] [image: -e^x]

Is it true that *decreased exponentially* often means *negative exponential increase* when used outside of mathematics? And if so what are good ways of clearly specifying which kind of decrease you are talking about.

Comment: In common use, "asymptotic" would be used for the first case, with "exponential" reserved for the second case.

Comment: Firstly, at [What is a better word for exponentially?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141739/what-is-a-better-word-for-exponentially) there is an answer showing that the word is often used in a sense less precise than the mathematical one (but echoing it). Then, by analogy, 'decreased exponentially' would be a paraphrase of 'decreased at a/n colossal / incredible / alarming ... rate'. // Is any increase / decrease in real life truly exponential in the strict sense (though radioactive decay gets close)? Isn't an exponential model just that?

Comment: Colloquially, it just means the number of fish *decreased drastically*.  It does allude to the fact that the decrease is trending in an almost exponential fashion.  However, It doesn't mean we are trying to quantify exactly how many fish have disappeared.

Comment: When you say "Mathematically this would mean a while ago the decrease was rapid, but rate of decrease has decreased" that is not true in a certain sense: Mathematically, the ratio rate of decrease does not decrease. It is decreasing at X% per unit of time.

Comment: As @edwinAshworth points out exponentially is actually rather rarely used correctly. For one if you say that the money you have put into your savings account is increasing exponentially people would be surprised though it's technically correct. So unless a mathematician of physician is using the word you should probbably assume it's used as an intensifier meaning large or fast. (btw. lot's of things in life are truly exponential locally, bacteria growth, credit card debts, lots of probabilty and certainly radioactive decay). It's just most of them are finitary in the end.

Comment: @Avon Mathematically it means exactly what the OP says. If you have an exponential decrease (i.e. e^{-kt}) then as time moves on i.e. t_1<t_2 the rate of decrease (the absolute value of the first derivative) decreases (i.e. |-ke^{-kt_1}|>|-ke^{-kt_2}|).

Comment: @DRF Yes but, another way of looking at it (and, I think, how it is often meant) the ratio rate of decrease remains constant. Just like the opposite of compound interest. So if the fish population were reducing at a constant 50% per year then that would be an exponential decrease. 50% per year can certainly be considered the rate of decrease and it doesn't decrease.

Comment: @avon Fair enough. The issue is the frivolous abuse of the term rate which is allowed in normal language. This is exactly the reason why everyone thinks that if the economy grew by 2% last year and 1.9% this year that growth must have slowed and then is all surprised that eventually we end up with market bubbles that crash.

Comment: @ DRF Edwin Ashworth does not label the more usual non-mathematical register usage 'incorrect' as you imply (usage defines correctness), but points out that knowledge of which register is being used can be vital. And the money in bank accounts cannot grow exponentially in the strict sense. Only continuous variables can have an exponential relationship. Bank accounts have a step-function relation to time, with arbitrary time intervals and rounded amounts of money, which is sensibly modelled by an exponential equation.

Comment: @edwinashworth If you want continuous variables then according to (how I understand quantization in) current physics nothing can be exponential since nothing is continuous, but that seems an unfortunate understanding. Even under that understanding though credit card interest is actually compounded continuously and the banks only round when you try and pay. Also I agree with usage defines correctness for language (though it pains me greatly when this must be extended to well defined mathematical terms).

Comment: @DRF A lot of 'money' seems to be virtual nowadays, so I'll not insist on fractions of a copper penny. So 'interest' may well have a virtual and an actual sense. But it would take an awful lot of paper to print out most instantaneous values worked out on a true exponential basis. And in any case, no bank I know measures time more accurately than 'completed days' when it comes to 'calculating interest'.

Answer (score 3):

It means the right figure.  I'm pretty sure most people who use the term exponentially aren't referencing any equation in their head.

Exponential has a very precise definition, but people just throw the word around to mean change very quickly, because this is how they have heard it used in the past and it sounded good.

In college I studied applied mathematics.  In my experience, many people who use these words have very little knowledge of the real definition.  Instead of focusing on the semantics of the sentence, you should use context of the conversation to determine what they mean.

Comment: Exactly. There are technical usages of words, and their non-technical usages. In a technical conversation, use the technical meaning. In a non-technical discussion, cut 'em some slack.

Comment: I agree that most people probably don't have a function in mind, but I am just wondering how many of the functions features people include. Would you say that exponential simply means 'change very quickly', or that it also encompasses 'at an increasing rate'

Comment: Without more context its hard to tell.  Certainly what you suggest is definitely true sometimes.  Given the provided sentence, your suggestion and mine are both possible.  I still think that colloquially its imprecise and that you need to hear the context to understand their definition.

Answer (score 1):

> Take the sentence:
>
> The number of fish in the lake has decreased exponentially over the past couple of years
>
> Mathematically this would mean a while ago the decrease was rapid, but rate of decrease has decreased

I disagree with your premise.

**Reason**

The basic structure of the sentence is: "The ***number*** of fish has decreased exponentially."

This does not mean that the rate of decrease has *decreased* as you state. It means that the rate of decrease has steadily *increased* over the period of time. There has been an acceleration.

You are confusing "decrease" with "rate of decrease".

**Non-mathematical use**

I agree with Alex W who says it could be used to mean "has decreased drastically."

Comment: I have to disagee with your disagreement. The OP's interpretation of [exponential decrease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) is pretty established in maths. It is exponetial in that it decreases at a rate proportional to its current value

Comment: What Tushar Raj said. While I agree about the non-mathematical use. The (correct)(mathematical) meaning of the sentence is what the OP points out.

Comment: @TusharRaj - I disagree with your disagreement of my disagreement.  In your comment you say "***it** " decreases at a rate proportional ..." but you haven't stated what "it" is. This is crucial. Perhaps you could give your own answer - I'd genuinely be interested.

Comment: 'It' is (the decrease in) the number of fish in the lake.

Comment: If I read in the *newspaper* this statement about the exponential decrease in the number of fish in the lake, I would understand it to mean that at the first census, they noticed that X fish were gone compared to their baseline.  At the next census, they noticed that (x * x) more fish were gone, at the third census, that (x * x * x) more fish were gone. With each census, the size of the drop in the population has increased exponentially.

Comment: @TusharRaj - You reply that  **"It'** is (the decrease in) the number of fish in the lake". That is my point of disagreement precisely. "It" in the original question does not have any bracketed "(the decrease in)". You have unjustifiably added that to the sentence and thereby given it a different menaing. If your rewriting was accurate then I would agree with you but it isn't.

Comment: An exponential increase in the number of fish being lost from the lake is a very different thing to an exponential decrease in the number of fish in the lake. That people may mean the former when they say the latter might be true but they are wrong to.

Comment: @Avon - You are of course right in what you say but I don't think anyone has claimed that "an exponential increase in the number being lost" is the same as "an exponential decrease". I certainly didn't.

Comment: But chasly that is exactly what you are saying people mean by exponential decrease: "the rate of decrease has steadily increased over the period of time." That is an exponential increase in the numbers being lost. The right hand graph in the OP's question.

Comment: @Avon - Everything you say is mathematically correct. What I disagree with is your saying that I equated ""an exponential increase in the number being lost" with "an exponential decrease".  I would say that  "a ***linear*** increase in the number being lost" is an equivalent statement.  "This is because the number being lost" is a **rate**, not a constant as you seem to imply by your criticism. "The number being lost" is not the same as "the number of fish". - it is a decrement that changes linearly with time thus causing an exponential decrease in the actual number of fish.

Comment: @chasly: I added the brackets to avoid any confusion in _my_ previous comment which has two `it`s. The OP didn't have to clarify anything. I kinda see your point, though. But, as Avon points out, you are on the wrong track.

Comment: @Tushar Raj - As I pointed out to Avon with clear reasons, I am on the right track. I studied mathematics and I know the difference between a number, an increment, a rate and an acceleration. I am absolutely confident of my correctness. I suggest you read what I actually said, not what you think I said. (Sorry to be blunt - No offence meant :-)

Comment: @chasly: None taken. And I re-read your post. I totally understand your point. And I'd _really_ like to believe you. (I'm _very_ disappointed when English isn't logical). But, consider this: _"the number has increased exponentially"_  means "the number has increased at an exponential rate", right? Similarly,  _"the number has decreased exponentially"_ is taken to mean "the number has decreased at an exponential rate; which isn't the case. The case, as you correctly point out, is that the 'rate of decrease' has increased (exponentially); which can in no way be understood from the original stmt.